# save coin count securely in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, security, nsuserdefaults

I have tried searching over net and found a way to securely save in-app purchase boolean variable in keychain. But what I want is to save count as user defaults can be easily manipulated by the user.

Comment: Why dnt u use encryption?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Anyway if you want to some user related data NSUserDefaults is an option, also can save this in keychain.

Comment: You can't. It's that simple. And you can't save a bool securely either.

Answer (score 0):

you can always convert your value to NSString and save it in keychain and convert it back after reading